# CPU Miner for Mac OSX?

Tags: cpu-mining, macos, miners

I'm new to the Monero community, but I've successfully mined many other cryptocurrencies. After a couple hours of digging, I could not find a pre-built CPU miner for OSX. Could someone point me in the right direction?

I found a few that require source code downloads and builds, but I'm looking for something precompiled that I can put my config settings into and be on my way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because I couldn't find anything and didn't receive any help here, I wanted to share what I ended up doing to help others in the future. This is what I did to mine on NiceHash on OSX Sierra:

1. [Install Docker](https://www.docker.com/products/overview)
2. Open Terminal
3. Run `docker run hmage/cpuminer-opt -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://cryptonight.usa.nicehash.com:3355 -O [YOURMONEROADDRESS].[YOURWORKERNAME]:x`

Comment: Don't you mean Run "docker run hmage/cpuminer-opt -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://cryptonight.usa.nicehash.com:3355 -O [YOUR**Monero**ADDRESS].[YOURWORKERNAME]:x" ?

Comment: x is the password in this case at the end..?

Comment: where did you get cpuminer-opt? the one from pooler i think only supported sha256d and scrypt.

Comment: Remember, if you want to have the maximum hashrate, increase the number of CPUs Docker uses in its preferences.

Comment: I got some error: '$ docker run hmage/cpuminer-opt -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://cryptonight.usa.nicehash.com:3355 -O whatever.mysetis:x
Unable to find image 'hmage/cpuminer-opt:latest' locally' reinstall or what?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you just want to pool mine, the monero daemon can CPU solo mine, and precompiled macOS executables are avaiable at https://getmonero.org/downloads/. Just tell monerod how many cores to use and your address, and you are on your way...

Comment: wouldn't solo mine be very risky as you throw away most of your hashing for a block that you may or may not ever get?

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded xmr-stack-cpu from here: http://macminer.fabulouspanda.com/commandline/xmrstakamd/

You can also build it yourself. I know you asked for something precompiled, but just in case:
https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak/blob/master/doc/compile_MacOS.md

Answer (score 2):

I tried to build from https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak/blob/master/doc/compile_MacOS.md

with this cmake command

`cmake . -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl -DCUDA_ENABLE=OFF -DOpenCL_ENABLE=ON`

It works. From the logs, my GPU is working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have been using **YAM** CPU miner for some time. You can download it from [mega.nz](https://mega.nz/#F!h0tkXSxZ!f62uoUXogkxQmP2xO8Ib-g). Note that that website doesn't support Safari properly. Either use Chrome or Firefox (or Tor Browser) instead.

Binaries are OS and CPU architecture specific. Examples:

- Mac mini (late 2009) is Core2 architecture, so select `yam-yvg1900-M8a-macos64-core2.tgz`.
- MacBook Pro (late 2013) is Haswell architecture, so select `yam-yvg1900-M8a-macos64-haswell.tgz`.

If you don't know what CPU architecture your specific Apple computer has, check out the [EveryMac.com website](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/index-apple-specs-applespec.html). Lookup your Apple computer, the architecture should be noted in the Processor Details section.

Mark the appropriate `.tgz` files in the browser with a ★ and click <kbd>Download as ZIP</kbd>. The resuling file is `jhProtominer.zip`. Unzip the file. Then unzip the appropriate archive concerning your platform, e.g.: `yam-yvg1900-M8a-macos64-haswell.tgz`. Then, the `yam` utility is in a subdirectory `macos64-haswell`. Transfer this directory to `/opt` or another location of your choice.

You can then either start the `yam` utility directly from a Terminal, or make a wrapper script. That could look like this (using pool [minexmr.com](http://minexmr.com) for example):

```
#!/bin/sh
NICE=20
OS="macos64"
# ARCH="core2"
ARCH="haswell"
WALLET_ADDRESS="4**********************************************************************************************"
PORT=4444 # mineXMR.com "Low end hardware"
# PORT=5555 # mineXMR.com "Mid range hardware"
# PORT=7777 # mineXMR.com "High end hardware"
nice -n ${NICE} /opt/${OS}-${ARCH}/yam -c x -M stratum+tcp://$ {WALLET_ADDRESS}:x@pool.minexmr.com:${PORT}/xmr
```

Note that you can simply stop YAM or your wrapper script with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. There's no session state to take care of.